# How can I find out if an instance is a MarshalByRef proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, marshalling, marshalbyrefobject

I know there's a way, I know I've done it (a long time) before, but I can't remember or find out how to do it!!!

```
var otherDomain = AppDomain.Create("Lol my memory sucks");
var myRemotableType = typeof(MyTypeThatExtendsMBRO);
var proxy = otherDomain
    .CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
      type.Assembly.FullName, 
      type.FullName);
// how do you do this next step???
bool isProxy = IsYouIsOrIsYouAintAProxy(proxy);
```

Comment: I love the self-descriptive code there.  +1 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the [`RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.istransparentproxy(v=VS.90).aspx) method.